# R fails to save files in the current working directory

Tags: r, directory, save

My files are failed to be saved in the correct directory in R. For example, my working directory is `/folder/subfolder`, but when I save files, they are all saved in `/folder`. When I use `getwd` or reset `setwd` to the `subfolder`, R shows that I'm in the one I want (`/folder/subfolder`). Is there anyone knows why?

I'm saving plots and model output on Mac OS:

```
setwd("/folder/subfolder")

getwd()
"/folder/subfolder"

list.files()
"group.jpg"                   
"Stake.htm"

stargazer(model, out = "sampleOutput")
jpeg("sample.jpg")
plot(sample, horiz = F)
dev.off()

list.file()
"group.jpg"                   
"Stake.htm"
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you try to save files? CSV, RData or RDS? What operating system are you using?

Comment: @JonGrub thanks for the reminder, I have updated my question.

Comment: can you edit your question to show the results of `getwd()` before and `list.files()` after your attempts to save?

Comment: BTW, `stargazer` has an `out` argument but no `output` argument ...

Comment: @BenBolker thx, a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try jpeg("/subfolder/sample.jpg")? That should force R to save to the subfolder.

Comment: I have tried that, but there is an error `No such file or directoryError in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : cannot open the connection`.

Comment: Can you try the things recommended in Maurice Reeves' answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156445/why-i-get-this-error-writing-data-to-a-file ? It's possible that you need to run R as an administrator to get that command to work (?).